Splunk Dashboard Studio - Source Code ERROR
What I am basically trying to do is display a particular colour for rows as per the values fetched in Splunk Dashboard studio.
So here is the JSON source code for that
{
    "type": "ds.search",
    "options": {
        "query": "index = index host=hostname source=\"/var/log/history-*.log\" servername | table Websphere GUI  \n| eval Websphere=if(Websphere=\"0\",\"UP\",\"DOWN\")\n| eval GUI=if(GUI=\"0\",\"UP\",\"DOWN\")",
        "queryParameters": {
            "earliest": "-10m@m",
            "latest": "now"
        },
        "refresh": "10m",
        "refreshType": "delay"
    },
    "options": {
        "columnFormat": {
            "Websphere": {
                "rowBackgroundColors": "> table | seriesByName(\"Websphere\") | matchValue(WebsphereColumnFormatConfig)"
            }
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "WebsphereColumnFormatConfig": [
            {
               "match": "DOWN",
               "value": "#FF0000"
           },
           {
               "match": "UP",
               "value": "#00FF00"
           }, 
       ]
    }

    "name": "DC Web Server _ search"
}

When I am adding it to source code section of Splunk.it is throwing me an error like this.enter image description here
I tried editing the JSON but not sure how additional properties can be incorporated as I am newbie in programming.
